# Integrating a function over a rectangle

Tags: geometry, vector-analysis

I was just wondering why we integrate functions over shapes such as rectactcles, or circles.

So, if we integrate a function between two points sit represents its area. But if we integrate a function over a double integral, what does this represent?

Sorry if this seems a silly question, I'm just having trouble understanding it.

Comment: Imagine a unit cube sitting on the rectangle with vertices $(0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,1)$ on $x,y$ plane. If you integrate $z=f(x,y)=1$ over  this rectangle, you will get the volume of unit cube.

Comment: It can represent a volume, but it doesn't have to.  Just as a standard integral isn't necessarily area.  For example energy is the integral of force over distance.  Double integrals are commonly used to find surface area, and electromagnetic flux.

Comment: But if I integrate f(x,y)=x^2 over the rectangle user160738 describes what would this represent?

Answer (score 1):

When you integrate a function of **one** variable, say $f(x)=2x+1$ from say $x=0$ to $x=2$, you get the **area under the graph** (a part of a triangle, in a sense, in this case). In this example, that area is

$\int_0^2 \! 2x+1 \, \mathrm{d}x=6$.

You can say that we integrate $f(x)$ **over** a interval, namely $[0,2]$.

When you then integrate a function of **two** variables, say $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, you have two variables that can change. If you were to plot $g(x,y)$, what would it look like? It would be a surface in three dimensions, since for each $x$ and $y$ (i.e a point in the xy-plane) you get a point $g(x,y)$ that can be plotted on the $z$-axis. (Use [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) to plot this yourself or look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2By%5E2).)

Now **under this graph** (i.e surface), you can choose a rectangle in the xy-plane, for example. Integrating **over** this rectangle will then mean that you let both $x$ and $y$ vary and thus get a double integral. For example

$\iint\limits_D \, x^2+y^2 \mathrm{d} x\,\mathrm{d} y$

where we integrate over the rectangle we just call $D$. Of course we need to specify the limits for the variables, for example $-0.5\leq x \leq 0.5$ and $-0.5 \leq y \leq 0.5$. In this case the double integral above would be $\frac{1}{6}$.

This integral will be the volume of the 'stuff' (or **volume under the graph**) between the surface (i.e the graph of g) and the xy-plane in the same way as the simple-integral represented the area between the line (i.e graph of f) and the interval [0,2].

I hope this makes things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

This represents volume. In general, integration increases the object being characterized by one dimension.